# Update purchasePrice on Purchase Line from Trade Agreement

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I have to update purchase orders that were created in past. Requirement is to update the purchase price by applying new trade agreements that were created later in the system after the purchase order creation. I have written a piece of code but the combinations in trade agreement are endless.

Is there any faster way to get the price that is active for the combinations?

Thank you

```
public static PriceDiscTable checkPriceDiscTable(PriceDiscAccountRelation    _accountRelation,
                                                 PriceDiscItemRelation       _itemRelation,
                                                 InventLocationId            _inventLocationId)
{
    RecId              priceDiscTableRec;
    PriceDiscTable      priceDiscTable;
    TableGroupAll               accountCode, ItemCode;
    PriceDiscAccountRelation    accountRelation;
    PriceDiscItemRelation       itemRelation;

    int     totalcases = 3;
    int     prioritycase = 0;

    while(prioritycase < totalcases)
    {
        switch (priorityCase)
        {
            case 0:
                accountCode         = TableGroupAll::Table;
                accountRelation     = _accountRelation;
                itemCode            = TableGroupAll::Table;
                itemRelation        = _itemRelation;

                priceDiscTableRec = DAL_PriceFromAgrement::findPriceDiscTable(accountCode, accountRelation,
                                                                                itemCode, itemRelation, _inventLocationId);
                priceDiscTable = PriceDiscTable::findRecId(priceDiscTableRec);
                if(priceDiscTable.recId)
                {
                    return priceDiscTable;
                }
                break;

            case 1:
                accountCode         = TableGroupAll::GroupId;
                accountRelation     = _accountRelation;
                itemCode            = TableGroupAll::Table;
                itemRelation        = _itemRelation;

                priceDiscTableRec = DAL_PriceFromAgrement::findPriceDiscTable(accountCode, accountRelation,
                                                                                itemCode, itemRelation, _inventLocationId);
                if(priceDiscTable.recId)
                {
                    return priceDiscTable;
                }
                break;

            case 2:
                accountCode         = TableGroupAll::All;
                accountRelation     = "";
                itemCode            = TableGroupAll::Table;
                itemRelation        = _itemRelation;

                priceDiscTableRec = DAL_PriceFromAgrement::findPriceDiscTable(accountCode, accountRelation,
                                                                                itemCode, itemRelation, _inventLocationId);
                if(priceDiscTable.recId)
                {
                    return priceDiscTable;
                }
                break;
        }
        prioritycase++;
    }

    return priceDiscTable;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The helper class is already there to do this for you.

The class name is `PriceDisc`.

Take a look at the method `purchPriceAgreement` on `InventTable`.

```
...
vendTable= VendTable::find(_accountNum);

priceDisc = new PriceDisc(ModuleInventPurchSales::Purch,
                              this.ItemId,
                              _inventDim,
                              inventTableModule.UnitId,
                              _priceDate,
                              _qty,
                              vendTable.AccountNum,
                              _currencyCode);

    if (!priceDisc.findPrice(vendTable.PriceGroup, false))

...

price       = priceDisc.price();
priceMarkup = priceDisc.markup();
priceUnit   = priceDisc.priceUnit();
...
etc
```

Comment: Thank you, but I used the method in PurchLine, setPriceDisc which does all the calculations

Comment: @Axer it also does a lot more. You specifically asked for trade agreement price and i gave you the code.